# smtplib* ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python, smtplib

when I use smtplib to sent email, there are always something wrong:

```
import smtplib
my_email = "XXXX@gmail.com"
password = "YYYY"


connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", port=587)
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email,to_addrs="VVVV", msg="hello")
connection.close()
```

I did it as the tutorial said, but the result was "ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)"

Is there something wrong in my system?

I just did it as the tutorial step by step, and sometimes it said:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tl5I.png)

Comment: Please paste text rather than including screenshots of error messages